# Total commander: Command to change current folder to the same path on a different drive

Tags: command-line, total-commander

I'm new to superuser things and I'm trying to make a command to swap between the same project on different drives. I'm working with a structure similar to this.

```
i:           k:         l:
 Project1     Project1   Project1
  data         data       data
  info         info       info
 Project2     Project2   Project2
  data         data       data
  info         info       info
```

I'm trying to make a command that swaps between the drives but goes to the same project i'm working in.

so far I have this: `cd /d %cd:i:=k:%` which works in the CLI but not in Total Commander.
I have it as a command in the usercmd.ini as:

```
[em_SwapDrive]
button=
cmd=cd /d %cd:i:=k:%;
```

How can I make this work?

Any tips in making this dynamic to to swap to the next drive also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to switch from current path to drive K: with same path:

```
for %a in ("%CD%") do cd "K:%~pnxa"
```

or

```
for /f "Delims=" %a in ('cd') do cd "K:%~pnxa"
```

Comment: This gives me a file not found error with the command below it. It does work in the CLI.

Comment: Do the 3 file structures already exist or do you have to create them first?